# Comparing close-enough numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

The following JavaScript abnormality caught me off-guard:

```
console.log(1 - 0.1 - 0.1 === 1 - 0.2); // true
console.log(1 - 0.2 - 0.2 === 1 - 0.4); // false
```

when I started testing some math, using Mocha test framework.

Is there a standard way in Mocha to compare numbers with a negligible decimal difference?

I am looking for a solution where it is possible to specify the comparison accuracy as percentage.

**UPDATE**

So basically I need to implement a function like this:

```
/**
 * @param a
 * @param b
 * @param accuracy - precision percentage.
 * @returns
 * 0, if the difference is within the accuracy.
 * -1, if a < b
 * 1, if a > b
 */
function compare(a, b, accuracy) {
}
```

The complexity is that `accuracy` is a percent value.

Examples:

```
compare(1.001, 1.002, 0.1) => 0
compare(12345, 12346, 0.1) => 0
```

Comment: Pick an "epsilon" value (some small number) and check if `Math.abs()` of the difference is smaller than that. This is not strictly a JavaScript problem; any language based on IEEE 754 floating point would have the same issue.

Comment: @Pointy When numbers vary from large to tiny ones, there is no such thing as some fixed small enough number. One needs to use a percentage of difference between the numbers that are compared. Like 0.01%, for example, so when the difference is below that compared to the numbers themselves, they can be considered equal. That's how it works when you are testing math models.

Comment: Oh yes, I understand that. It's a complicated problem.

Comment: You basically answered your own question after a single hint - probably worth deleting the question again.

Answer (score 1):

Mocha is a test runner / framework. It just cares about whether something throws an error or not within the test. Assertions/checks belong to assertion libraries – it's not something that Mocha takes care of / provides functionality for. You're free to use any assertion library with Mocha, like chai or unexpected. See the whole list here: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki

And from your comment, you'll probably get by with something like:

```
function compare(a, b, accuracy) {
  const biggest = Math.max(Math.abs(a), Math.abs(b))
  const epsilon = biggest * accuracy
  if (Math.abs(a - b) > epsilon) {
    throw(new Error("message"))
  }
}
```